# How to add string into an already existing line (bash)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a file with the next format (**please, note that after the numbers there is NO a whitespace character**):

```
430
670
230
```

For example, lets say I wanna add some text to 2nd existing line, resulting in:

```
430 
670 /foo/oof
230
```

I have seen some tutos using `sed`, `ed`, and even `awk` but all of them just insert the text in a line, not **after** an existing text in a line.

Comment: If you have read about sed then `sed '/670/~s~$~ /foo/oof~' infile` should have popped up.

Comment: Hi mate, the numbers are variables and I don't have control over them, I just have control over the number line, that's what I can't use your way

Comment: Sure address line 2 by its number like `sed '2s~$~ /foo/oof~'`. If you want to use `sed` more often, I strongly suggest referring to this very good [tutorial](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) - also heartly recommended for REGEX and `awk`.

Comment: Thanks mate, I will read it right now